# Please Suggest me Open Source Tools for automating GUI Map Interface

Tags: automation

Currently, I am using Sikuli for Automating Map Interface. Since, it is not effective, I would like tp try with some other open source tools.  Please suggest good tool.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at this : http://alternativeto.net/software/sikuli/

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. AutoHotkey has very strong support for GUI automation. In fact you can automate anything with AutoHotkey, not only GUI.
Also keep in mind that AutoHotkey has very friendly and helpful community.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*